# Interface 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider' cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

This used to work.

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
Function Widget(ByVal collection As FormCollection) As ActionResult
    ...
    If ... Then
        ModelState.AddModelError(...)
        ModelState.SetModelValue("Gadget", collection.ToValueProvider("Gizmo"))
        Return View()
    End If
    ...
End Function
```

I upgraded to **ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta** and **ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures Assembly for Beta** and now `ToValueProvider()` fails with this compile-time error:

> Interface
>   'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider' cannot
>   be indexed because it has no default
>   property

How do I use `ModelState.SetModelValue()` if not with `collection.ToValueProvider()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract taken from the ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta release notes:

> **Changes in ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta**
>
> Introduced the IValueProvider
>   interface, which replaces all usages
>   of IDictionary<string,
>   ValueProviderResult>.
>
> Every property or method argument that
>   accepted IDictionary<string,
>   ValueProviderResult> now accepts
>   IValueProvider. This change affects
>   only applications that include custom
>   value providers or custom model
>   binders.
>
> Examples of properties and methods
>   that are affected by this change
>   include the following:
>
> - The ValueProvider property of the ControllerBase and ModelBindingContext
>     classes.
> - The TryUpdateModel methods of the Controller class.
> - New CSS classes were added in the Site.css file that are used to style
>     validation messages.

HTHs,
Charles

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the string parameter.

Wrong:

```
collection.ToValueProvider("Gizmo")
```

Correct:

```
collection.ToValueProvider()
```

---

### Update

Creates a new run-time error after published to web server:

> Method not found:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider
>   System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection.ToValueProvider()'.

Download and install **.NET Framework 4 Beta 2** onto web server.

[Microsoft Download Center: Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Beta 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ded875c8-fe5e-4cc9-b973-2171b61fe982&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following and it's working.

ModelState.SetModelValue("Gadget", ValueProvider.GetValue(ControllerContext, "Gizmo"));

Haven't tried to deploy it yet.